# Use of ampersands for nested conjunctions

Tags: conjunctions, lists, coordinating-conjunctions, ampersand

Consider the sentence:

"The zoo contained giraffes, white & black rhinos, and Indian & African elephants."

Here ampersands are used for the inner conjunctions, but not the outer level.

Is there any precedent for this?

I find it improves the appearance of such sentences, and helps clarify the nesting structure.

Comment: I've seen it used but it's more of an issue of style than of language usage.

Comment: I would see your example as "misuse" -- Ampersand "&" is now seldom used to replace "and" *other than in titles and company names*. In Old and Middle English "&" was often used in lists in common writing: *OE   Wulfstan Sermo ad Anglos (Nero) (1957) 273   Her syndan mannslagan & mægslagan & mæsserbanan & mynsterhatan; & her syndan mansworan & morþorwyrhtan; & her syndan myltestran & bearnmyrðran & fule forlegene horingas manege*" but, by the 18th century this had largely fallen out of use. The current advice is not to use "&" in lists at all.

Comment: It is a useful style in the quoted context, as it makes it clear that the two "anded" words belong together as a single semantic entity in the larger context.  Especially useful when the larger context contains "and", potentially causing confusion on the part of the reader if "and" were used throughout.